# Transformation of two independent uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, self-learning, transformation

Suppose $X,Y \sim \text{Uniform} \left(0,1 \right)$ are independent. Then I need to find the PDF for $W=X/Y$.

By the CDF technique this is seen to be :

$$F_W( w)=\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{wy} \mathrm{dxdy}=w/2$$

And therefore

$f_W (w)= 1/2 $, a uniform distribution on $(0,2)$

My question is, assuming that I have not made a mistake anywhere, what is the intuition behind this result? I would think that since $Y$ can be close to zero the quotient would be unbounded. Instead it seems that it can only take values up to $2$.

Thank you.

Comment: Your intuition is right, there is a mistake in the setting up of the integral. To set it up correctly, draw a coordinate plane, draw the square on which the joint density lives, and draw the line $x=yw$. The geometry depends on the value of $w$.

Comment: $W \equiv x/y \in \left(0,\infty\right)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. Indeed the geometry changes. However I'm getting a negative pdf for the triangle involving $w>1$. The vertices are $(0,0), (1/w,0),(1/w,1)$ and therefore the area I find is $\frac{1}{2w}$ and upon differentiating $-\frac{1}{2w^2}$.

Comment: You probably found the probability that  the ratio is $\gt w$. There are good answers already, if trouble remains I will write up something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is
\begin{align}
F_W(w)&=\Pr[W\leq w]\\
&=\Pr[X/Y\leq w]\\
&=\Pr[X\leq wY]&\text{(because $Y\geq0$)}\\
&=\Pr[(X,Y)\in\{(x,y)\in(0,1)\times(0,1):x\leq wy\}].
\end{align}
Let us denote $A(w)=\{(x,y)\in(0,1)\times(0,1):x\leq wy\}.$
Then,
since $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
we see that
\begin{align*}
F_W(w)=\int_{A(w)}~d(x,y).
\end{align*}

As hinted in Michael's answer,
the way we parametrize $A(w)$ will depend on $w$ itself:

**1.** If $w\geq 1$,
then $x$ can take any value in $(0,1)$,
and for any fixed $x$,
$y$ has to be such that $x/w\leq y\leq1$,
thus
\begin{align*}
F_W(w)=\int_0^1\int_{x/w}^{1}~dydx=\int_0^1(1-x/w)~dx=1-1/(2w).
\end{align*}
This makes sense from a geometrical point of view,
because in this case,
$A(w)$ is the square $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ to which you remove the triangle $T$ with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1/w)$; and $T$ has an area of $1/2\times 1\times 1/w$.

**2.** If $0<w\leq 1$,
then $y$ can take any value from $0$ to $1$,
but $x$ is restricted to $0\leq x\leq wy$
\begin{align*}
F_W(w)=\int_0^1\int_{0}^{wy}~dxdy=w/2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. My question is how do you determine in $1$ that $x$ can take any value in $(0,1)$ and in $2$ that it is the $y$ that can take any value in $(0,1)$?

Comment: This choice is made clear when you draw the region $A(w)$ and think of how you should parametrize it. For **1.**, you *could* say that $y$ takes any value in $[0,1]$, but then when you try to get the constraints on $x$ for a fixed $y$, the contraints will depend on $y$: If $y\leq 1/w$, then $0\leq x\leq wy$, and if $y>1/w$, then $0\leq x\leq 1$. This will necessitate to split the integral $F_W(w)$ in two parts, and is slightly more complicated than letting $x$ take any value and then pick $x/w\leq y\leq 1$.

Comment: As for **2.**, the region $A(w)$ consists of the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(w,1)$, and so it is clear in this case that $x$ definitely cannot take any values in $(w,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

If the ratio is less than 1, then I agree the PDF is 1/2.

If the ratio is above 1, then I think the PDF is $1/2w^2$.

The set of values $(x,y)$ with $w<y/x<w+dw$ is a triangle with vertices at $(0,0),(1/w,1)$ and $(1/(w+dw),1)$.  Its area is roughly $dw/(2w^2)$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#88f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\delta\pars{w - {x \over y}}\dd x\,\dd y}
=\Theta\pars{w}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\delta\pars{x - wy} \over \verts{1/y}}
\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=\Theta\pars{w}\int_{0}^{1}y\,\Theta\pars{1 - wy}\,\dd y
=\Theta\pars{w}\int_{0}^{1}y\,\Theta\pars{{1 \over w} - y}\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=\Theta\pars{w}\Theta\pars{1 - {1 \over w}}\int_{0}^{1/w}y\,\dd y
+\Theta\pars{w}\Theta\pars{{1 \over w} - 1}\int_{0}^{1}y\,\dd y
\\[5mm]&=\Theta\pars{w}\bracks{{\Theta\pars{w - 1} \over 2w^{2}}
+{\Theta\pars{1 - w} \over 2}}
=\color{#88f}{\large\left\lbrace\begin{array}{ccl}
0 & \color{#000}{\mbox{if}} & w < 0
\\[3mm]
\half & \color{#000}{\mbox{if}} & 0 < w \leq 1
\\[3mm]
{1 \over 2w^{2}} & \color{#000}{\mbox{if}} & w > 1
\end{array}\right.}
\end{align}

> [image]